How to Properly Use Render Layers in Blender for Smoke Overlays and Scene Compositing?
Can anyone help me figure out how to properly set up render layers so that the result looks correct, like in a regular render?

If I enable holdout, the black shadow disappears but I get a "hole"
in the render.
If I disable holdout, the "hole" is gone, but the black shadow
reappears.

Film > Transparent is enabled
Any advice on how to solve this?



I don't understand your setup, I see only one layer being used. If I'm not mistaking, you should Alpha Over your smoke layer on top of the render (as in your nodes). Try simplifying your blend file to a minimum, pack the textures and share it so that we don't have to guess anything : https://blend-exchange.com/

hey @Lutzi thanks for the reply! i added a blend file to the post

@Lutzi, please test it on frames 50-55, and don’t forget to bake the smoke simulation
